# How to convert image using filter

Tags: html, css

I have a simple Image Which contain transparent and red color

I want to change this color to yellow using  filter  in css3

Here is what I have so far

HTML

```
 <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iaXi.png" class="image">
```

Here is css

```
.image {
    filter: saturate(3); 
}
```

I tried to play with different option I couldnt solve the problem.

What do I need to change to get the yellow color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `hue-rotate` CSS filter, combined with the `brightness` CSS filter. For your image, to turn it to yellow use:

HTML

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iaXi.png" class="image">
```

CSS

```
.image {
    filter: hue-rotate(60deg) brightness(180%);
}
```

Combine multiple CSS filters by separating them with a space.

https://codepen.io/mikeabeln_nwea/pen/wRvBxa

Comment: Mike why it affect also color of other details in a container?

Comment: I've updated the codepen to explain this, if you put the class on the container, it will style the children. If the class is on the image, it will not.

Comment: Thanks Mike , I meaan I am trying to use  this image as background , here is effect I get when I adding as background, it affect other details color in a card https://imgur.com/a/RHWeQph

Comment: Ohh I see what you're trying to do. My answer was tailored to your specific question – styling an image tag with a filter. Your question is actually how to apply a filter to an element with a `background-image`, without affecting other content in the element? Here is a good article that explains that scenario: https://css-tricks.com/apply-a-filter-to-a-background-image/

Comment: Thanks Mike exactly that is what I wanted , solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `sepia` filter

```css
.sepia-filter {
  -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
  filter: sepia(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" class="sepia-filter">
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" >
```

Comment: here is jsfiddle gives me grey did u try it? http://jsfiddle.net/aJDBy/253/

Comment: It sounds like your browser doesn't support the `filter`

Comment: More about filters: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

Comment: am using chrome :)

Answer (score 2):

i finally found. this is yellow :)

```css
.image {
  filter:sepia(12) saturate(8) brightness(2);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iaXi.png" class="image">
```

Comment: let me check if it does not affect otherdeatils color

Comment: yeah works but it affect other details when I use it as background: 
`.pricing-box.premium {
    grid-area: premium;
    background-image: url('/images//price-bg.png');
    background-position: bottom;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    filter:sepia(12) saturate(8) brightness(2);
}`  but thanks alot